# How do I put mathematical operations in a list?

Tags: python, list, random, operators

I need to make my code as short as possible and I need to put * - + in a list like this: op = [*,-,+]

It gives me a syntax error... I know I can put them as strings but is that the only way? My program picks a random operator from that list and makes a sum out of it, eg, sum = num1 op num2

my code:

```
import random

opL = [*,-,+]

def mathsQuiz(number1,operator,number2):
    sum1=number1,operator,number2
    print(sum1)

number1 = random.randint(1,12)
number2 = random.randint(1,12)
operator = random.choice(opL)

mathsQuiz(number1,operator,number2)
```

Comment: *"I need to make my code as short as possible"* - why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator) module and create a dictionary instead that will map out your operators:

```
>>> import operator
>>> import random
>>> opL = {"*": operator.mul, "-": operator.sub, "+": operator.add}
>>> opL.get(random.choice(list(opL)))(1,2)
3
```

Comment: Or `opL.get(random.choice(opL))(1,2)`, since the OP wants to randomly select some operator.

Comment: How do i randomize which operator is chosen?

Comment: @DilsaajanDuggal Look at the updated solution. For my solution you will need to get the `keys()` to extract the operator you want.

Comment: @idjaw - wow, you are right! I would call that a bug in `random.choice`, since iterating over a dict should give you the keys.

Comment: Py3 problem perhaps? Probably better to do `opL.get(random.choice(list(opL)))`, which should work in both Py2 and Py3.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Yes. I just tested in Python 2 to make sure. I will update accordingly.

Comment: Works great, thanks @idjaw by any chance do you know how to print the whole calculation, for example if the calculation was operator.mul(1,2) how would I print "The question is..." 1*2?

Comment: Something like this. I leave the refactoring to you: `"The question is {} {} {}".format(1, random.choice(list(opL.keys())), 2)`

Comment: @idjaw - to reiterate/clarify, `list(opL)` is sufficient to get a list of a dict's keys, and works in both Py2 and Py3. No need to actually call `keys()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import operator
opL = operator.mul, operator.sub, operator.add
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain.  Since the OP already has a variable named `operator`, he is apt to be confused by your post.

Comment: If I wanted to explain, there would have been an explanation.

Comment: If you didn't want to explain, perhaps you shouldn't have answered.

Comment: In that case you can't be mad if people downvote this as unhelpful.